# Why do I get this error? TypeError: $popover.data(...) is undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

What is causing this to error onhover? The error is:

> TypeError: $popover.data(...) is undefined.

```
$(function () {

    var overPopup = false;

    $('[rel=popover]').popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'bottom'

    // replacing hover with mouseover and mouseout
    }).mouseover(function (e) {
        // when hovering over an element which has a popover, hide
        // them all except the current one being hovered upon
        $('[rel=popover]').not('#' + $(this).attr('id')).popover('hide');
        var $popover = $(this);
        $popover.popover('show');

        // set a flag when you move from button to popover
        // dirty but only way I could think of to prevent
        // closing the popover when you are navigate across
        // the white space between the two
        $popover.data('popover').tip().mouseenter(function () {
            overPopup = true;
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            overPopup = false;
            $popover.popover('hide');
        });

    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        // on mouse out of button, close the related popover
        // in 200 milliseconds if you're not hovering over the popover
        var $popover = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!overPopup) {
                $popover.popover('hide');
            }
        }, 200);
    });
});

<a href="#" id="example1" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" data-content="Example 1!!!" data-original-title="Example 1 title">Button 1</a>
<a href="#" id="example2" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" data-content="Example 2!!!" data-original-title="Example 2 title">Button 2</a>
<a href="#" id="example3" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" data-content="Example 3!!!" data-original-title="Example 3 title">Button 3</a>
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because either you are using older version of `jQuery` library OR you have not loaded `angularjs` library. I thought not any other reason for this error.